# React Native and Expo (Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined.)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting this error that is common.
I did a research here on Stackoverflow but I didn't find a solution for this code example problem. Don't know what it's causing it.

The error message:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

> Check the render method of 'Settings'.

The Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';

export default function Settings() {

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text style={styles.containerTitle}>Application Settings</Text>

            <Text style={styles.settingsTitle}>Temperature Unit</Text>
            <View style={styles.checkboxVariables}>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>Celsius</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>Fahrenheit</Text>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.settingsTitle}>Wind Speed Unit</Text>
            <View style={styles.checkboxVariables}>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>km/h</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>m/s</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>mph</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>kn</Text>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.settingsTitle}>Precipitation Unit</Text>
            <View style={styles.checkboxVariables}>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>Milimeter</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text style={styles.checkboxVariable}>Inch</Text>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.settingsTitle}>Timezone</Text>
            <Picker>

                <Picker.Item label="America/Anchorage" value="America/Anchorage" />
                <Picker.Item label="America/Los Angeles" value="America/Los Angeles" />
                <Picker.Item label="America/Denver" value="America/Denver" />
                <Picker.Item label="America/Chichago" value="America/Chichago" />
                <Picker.Item label="America/New York" value="America/New York" />
                <Picker.Item label="America/Sao Paulo" value="America/Sao Paulo" />
                <Picker.Item label="UTC" value="UTC" />
                <Picker.Item label="Europe/London" value="Europe/London" />
                <Picker.Item label="Europe/Berlin" value="Europe/Berlin" />
                <Picker.Item label="Europe/Moscow" value="Europe/Moscow" />
                <Picker.Item label="Africa/Cairo" value="Africa/Cairo" />
                <Picker.Item label="Asia/Bangkok" value="Asia/Bangkok" />
                <Picker.Item label="Asia/Singapore" value="Asia/Singapore" />
                <Picker.Item label="Asia/Tokyo" value="Asia/Tokyo" />
                <Picker.Item label="Australia/Sydney" value="Australia/Sydney" />
                <Picker.Item label="Pacific/Auckland" value="Pacific/Auckland" />

            </Picker>


            <Text style={styles.settingsTitle}>Past days</Text>
            <Picker>

                <Picker.Item label="0" value="0" />
                <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
                <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
                <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
                <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
                <Picker.Item label="1 week" value="1 week" />
                <Picker.Item label="2 weeks" value="2 weeks" />
                <Picker.Item label="1 month" value="1 month" />
                <Picker.Item label="2 months" value="2 months" />
                <Picker.Item label="3 months" value="3 months" />

            </Picker>

        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    containerTitle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 40,
        paddingTop: 50,
        color: '#51697f',
    },
    settingsTitle: {
        fontStyle: 'italic'
    },
    checkboxVariables: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        marginBottom: 10,
        padding: 10
    },
    checkboxVariable: {
        marginRight: 30,
    }
});
```

Also this is the App.js File:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import DrawerNavigator from './navigation/DrawerNavigator';


export default function App() {
  return (

    <NavigationContainer>

      <StatusBar style="auto" />

      <DrawerNavigator />

    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}
```

This is the error I get when I remove {} from CheckBox:

> requirenativecomponent: "rnccheckbox" was not found in the UImanager

When I import CheckBox from 'react-native' then I get the error on mobile app:

> CheckBox has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/checkbox' instead of 'react-native'.

But when I use in the web app everything is working good, there are no errors. Also when I use 'react-native-community/checkbox' and test it in the web app then I get the same error:

> Element type is invalid...

**react-native/Libraries/LogBox/Data/LogBoxData.js (194:30)**

```
export function addLog(log: LogData): void {
  const errorForStackTrace = new Error();

  // Parsing logs are expensive so we schedule this
  // otherwise spammy logs would pause rendering.
  setImmediate(() => {
    try {
      const stack = parseErrorStack(errorForStackTrace?.stack);

      appendNewLog(
        new LogBoxLog({
          level: log.level,
          message: log.message,
          isComponentError: false,
          stack,
          category: log.category,
          componentStack: log.componentStack,
        }),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      reportLogBoxError(error);
    }
  });
}
```

**react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js (21826:22)**

```
function createFiberFromTypeAndProps(
  type, // React$ElementType
  key,
  pendingProps,
  owner,
  mode,
  lanes
) {
  var fiberTag = IndeterminateComponent; // The resolved type is set if we know what the final type will be. I.e. it's not lazy.

  var resolvedType = type;

  if (typeof type === "function") {
    if (shouldConstruct(type)) {
      fiberTag = ClassComponent;

      {
        resolvedType = resolveClassForHotReloading(resolvedType);
      }
    } else {
      {
        resolvedType = resolveFunctionForHotReloading(resolvedType);
      }
    }
  } else if (typeof type === "string") {
    fiberTag = HostComponent;
  } else {
    getTag: switch (type) {
      case REACT_FRAGMENT_TYPE:
        return createFiberFromFragment(pendingProps.children, mode, lanes, key);

      case REACT_DEBUG_TRACING_MODE_TYPE:
        fiberTag = Mode;
        mode |= DebugTracingMode;
        break;

      case REACT_STRICT_MODE_TYPE:
        fiberTag = Mode;
        mode |= StrictLegacyMode;

        break;

      case REACT_PROFILER_TYPE:
        return createFiberFromProfiler(pendingProps, mode, lanes, key);

      case REACT_SUSPENSE_TYPE:
        return createFiberFromSuspense(pendingProps, mode, lanes, key);

      case REACT_SUSPENSE_LIST_TYPE:
        return createFiberFromSuspenseList(pendingProps, mode, lanes, key);

      case REACT_OFFSCREEN_TYPE:
        return createFiberFromOffscreen(pendingProps, mode, lanes, key);

      case REACT_LEGACY_HIDDEN_TYPE:
        return createFiberFromLegacyHidden(pendingProps, mode, lanes, key);

      case REACT_SCOPE_TYPE:

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-fallthrough

      case REACT_CACHE_TYPE:

      // eslint-disable-next-line no-fallthrough

      default: {
        if (typeof type === "object" && type !== null) {
          switch (type.$$typeof) {
            case REACT_PROVIDER_TYPE:
              fiberTag = ContextProvider;
              break getTag;

            case REACT_CONTEXT_TYPE:
              // This is a consumer
              fiberTag = ContextConsumer;
              break getTag;

            case REACT_FORWARD_REF_TYPE:
              fiberTag = ForwardRef;

              {
                resolvedType = resolveForwardRefForHotReloading(resolvedType);
              }

              break getTag;

            case REACT_MEMO_TYPE:
              fiberTag = MemoComponent;
              break getTag;

            case REACT_LAZY_TYPE:
              fiberTag = LazyComponent;
              resolvedType = null;
              break getTag;
          }
        }

        var info = "";

        {
          if (
            type === undefined ||
            (typeof type === "object" &&
              type !== null &&
              Object.keys(type).length === 0)
          ) {
            info +=
              " You likely forgot to export your component from the file " +
              "it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and " +
              "named imports.";
          }

          var ownerName = owner ? getComponentNameFromFiber(owner) : null;

          if (ownerName) {
            info += "\n\nCheck the render method of `" + ownerName + "`.";
          }
        }

        {
          throw Error(
            "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: " +
              (type == null ? type : typeof type) +
              "." +
              info
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var fiber = createFiber(fiberTag, pendingProps, key, mode);
  fiber.elementType = type;
  fiber.type = resolvedType;
  fiber.lanes = lanes;

  {
    fiber._debugOwner = owner;
  }

  return fiber;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what is the problem?
Do I need to define something else?
Testing it on iPhone and using the Expo App.

Comment: Can you paste the actual line (not its number, but the actual line of code) here in the comment section where the problem happens? Without that I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get this kind of error, pay attention to importing.

I looked documentation of '@react-native-community/checkbox'. You should import like this.

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
```

Comment: It is not helping getting the a new error, already tried it. I updated the text up, check it.

Comment: The error you get after doing this is completely different error, which does not mean that what you did is wrong. I suggest that you research the error on GitHub page of library. I cannot say anything because I don't know the details and there are many possibilities. I saw many people encountering same error.